# Finding Cell Location in Excel with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, conditional-formatting

I have cell objects that I am writing to from an array of information. What I am  trying to do is have it that the program will handle any size of array so the cells are being filled in dynamically i guess the term would be.

I am also trying to add conditional formatting to these cells as they are being added in, but the CellRangeAddress seems to need a string of the exact cells being formatted with Excel style addresses (A1,B3,F6 etc).

I have looked at the API but cant seem to find anything that returns this kind of value.

How do I get the Excel address of a cell?

Thanks in advance and apologies if I have missed something completely obvious or if the question is unclear.

Comment: If you've found the solution, then please post it as an answer, rather than editing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
 CellRangeAddress range =
    new CellRangeAddress(
           c1.getRowIndex(), c3.getRowIndex()
         , c1.getColumnIndex(), c3.getColumnIndex()
    );
```